# How to pass the subscribe function to the parent component?(Angular)

Tags: angular, rest

How can I pass the subscribe function where I get the info from a REST API from child component(agreements.component) to the parent component(home.component) and call it in the child component with event emitter in ngOnInit(). I would appreciate any help.
I attached the code.

CHILD COMPONENT agreements.component

```css
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-agreements',
  templateUrl: './agreements.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./agreements.component.sass']
})
export class AgreementsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() getBody = new EventEmitter<any>();
  private body;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.body=this.getBody.emit();
  }

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let b of body">{{b.body}}</li>
</ul>
```

THE SERVICE

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AgreementsService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

 // Uses http.get() to load data from a single API endpoint
 getBodyService(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  }
}
```

PARENT COMPONENT (home.component)

```css
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//import {Customer} from '../model/model';
import {AgreementsService} from '../home/agreements/agreements.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.sass']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  private body;
  constructor(private _agreementsService: AgreementsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getBody() {
    return this._agreementsService.getBodyService().subscribe(
        data => { this.body = data, console.log(data)},
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('done loading foods')
      )
    }

}
```

```html
<app-email></app-email>
<app-agreements (getBody)="getBody($event)"></app-agreements>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use **`EventEmitter`**. Pass the body as **`Input`** to Child Component.

**ParentComponent - HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="body">
 <app-agreements [body]="body"></app-agreements>
</div>
```

**ParentComponent - TS**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getBody();
  }

  getBody() {
    this._agreementsService.getBodyService().subscribe(
        data => { 
        this.body = data;
        },
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('done loading foods')
      )
  }
```

**ChildComponent - TS**

```
export class AgreementsComponent {

     @Input() body;

}
```

**See my [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-21-04-2019?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).**

Answer (score 1):

no you can't do that, but there is 2 options

- ViewChild

get app-agreements component in home-component by @ViewChild, and when the data comes you invoke app-agreements function like this

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./home.component.sass"]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  private body;

  @ViewChild(AgreementsComponent)
  agreementsComp: AgreementsComponent;

  constructor(private _agreementsService: AgreementsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  getBody() {
    return this._agreementsService.getBodyService().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.agreementsComp.processData(data);
      },
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log("done loading foods")
    );
  }
}
```

and inside agreements component add processData method.

a second and better option

- Property Binding

add input property to agreements component and when the data comes just assign it, and listen to ngOnChanges event in agreements component like this

```
export class AgreementsComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Output() getBody = new EventEmitter<any>();

  @Input() data: any;

  private body;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (data) {
      ///Do your logic here
    }
  }
}
```

and that's home component html

```
<app-agreements [data]="body" (getBody)="getBody($event)"></app-agreements>
```